# Simplify / elegantize this code?

Tags: javascript, function, simplify

Here's a bit of code which works fine but I think could be simplified / shortened. It's basically clicking on a list item, getting it's id and then showing / hiding / removing elements based on the id.

Suggestions on how to simplify this with a function or loop?

```
$("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {
    var selectedId = $(".selected-type").attr("id");
    if (selectedId == "temperature_event") {
        $("#poplist_temp").show();
        $(".temperature-params").hide();
        $("#temperature_event").remove();
    } else if (selectedId == "load_event") {
        $("#poplist_load").show();
        $(".load-params").hide();
        $("#load_event").remove();
    } else if (selectedId == "price_event") {
        $("#poplist_price").show();
        $(".price-params").hide();
        $("#price_event").remove();
    } else if (selectedId == "duty_event") {
        $("#poplist_duty").show();
        $(".duty-params").hide();
        $("#duty_event").remove();
    } else {
        $("#poplist_program").show();
        $(".program-params").hide();
        $("#program_event").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Consider looking at a [switch statement](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Fswitch&ei=nIqtVOCZJZCRyASEkIGICw&usg=AFQjCNFqQ_wcrCiKfLOGne_uhqHI2FWw1A&sig2=c-4R1hhiMeHJh9-wRkPe5g)

Comment: Use the switch statement, then generate a function that can be used to handle the show, hide, and remove based on which statement.

Comment: I would rename your ID's and use combined classes so that I could use one group of hide, show, remove actions.  If knew the structure of the HTML you are using, I could probably make it far simpler.

Comment: I think if you need something like you posted above, then maybe you should refactor your code entirely.

Comment: This should be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing my classes to ids and reordering them, so I ended up with this solution which doesn't require any if statements.

```
$("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {

    var selectedId = $(".selected-type").attr("id").split("_");
    $("#" + selectedId[0] + "_pop").show();
    $("#" + selectedId[0] + "_params").hide();
    $("#" + selectedId[0] + "_event").remove();

});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {
    var selectedId = $(".selected-type").attr("id");
    switch(selectedId){
        case "temperature_event":
        $("#poplist_temp").show();
        $(".temperature-params").hide();
        $("#temperature_event").remove();
        break;

        case "load_event":
        $("#poplist_load").show();
        $(".load-params").hide();
        $("#load_event").remove();
        break;

        case "price_event":
        $("#poplist_price").show();
        $(".price-params").hide();
        $("#price_event").remove();
        break;

        case "duty_event"):
        $("#poplist_duty").show();
        $(".duty-params").hide();
        $("#duty_event").remove();
        break;

        default:
        $("#poplist_program").show();
        $(".program-params").hide();
        $("#program_event").remove();
    }
});
```

Or even better:

```
$("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {
    // Get id and split on "_"
    var selectedId = $(".selected-type").attr("id").split("_");
    // Set array of accepted input
    var options = ["temperature","load","price","duty"];
    // Handle default
    if(options.indexOf(selectedId[0]) == -1){
       selectedId = ["program"];
    }

    $("#poplist_" + selectedId[0]).show();
    $("."+selectedId[0] + "-params").hide();
    $("#"+selectedId[0] + "_event").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity sake I would change the id of the buttons clicked to one word(tempeature,load,price,duty). You'll have to do some renaming of your reactionary ids/classes, but just looks cleaner to me. I also flipped some of your naming around to stay consistent.

You can switch it around to match your style, it just bothered me having selectors like $("#"+id+"-params").hide();

```
$("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {
        var selectedId = $(".selected-type").attr("id");
        var nonDefault = ["temperature","load","price","duty"];
        if(nonDefault.indexOf(selectedId) > -1){
            $("#poplist_"+selectedId).show();
            $(".params-"+selectedId).hide();
            $("#event_"+selectedId).remove();          
        } else {
            $("#poplist_program").show();
            $(".params-program").hide();
            $("#event_program").remove();
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your input. I have to use _event because the solo words are being used for something else already. This is part of a much bigger project so unfortunately the ids end up getting long in order to keep things grouped and sane. i.e. #duty, #duty_event, #duty_message, #duty_controls, etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on the ID names matching other element names, you can use an object as a map to specify actions.

```
//using a map lets you easily add or remove cases without duplicating code, and doesn't require you to use standardized names for your elements and events. 
    var action_map = {temperature_event:{show:"#poplist_temp",
                                         hide:".temperature-params",
                                         remove:"#temperature_event"
                                        },
                      load_event:{show:"#poplist_load",
                                  hide:".load-params",
                                  remove:"#load_event",
                                 },
                      price_event:{show:"#poplist_price",
                                   hide:".price-params",
                                   remove:"#price_event",
                                  },
                      duty_event:{show:"#poplist_duty",
                                  hide:".duty-params",
                                  remove:"#duty_event"
                                 },
                      default_event:{show:"#poplist_program",
                                     hide:".program-params",
                                     remove:"#duty_event",
                                    }
                     };

    $("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {
        var selectedId = $(".selected-type").attr("id");
        if (!action_map[selectedId]) 
            selectedId = "default_event";

            $(action_map[selectedId].show).show();
            $(action_map[selectedId].hide).hide();
            $(action_map[selectedId].remove).remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Personally the cleanest and most configurable way i can see is using a map and looping of the methods. This is generic as different mappings can have different methods. You can even extend this further so you can have a method which will construct the mappings for you.. i.e. addNewType([{methodName:selector}, etc..]).

```js
 var configuration = { 
        temperature_event: {
            show: "#poplist_temp",
            hide: ".temperature-params",
            remove: "#temperature_event"
        },
        load_event: {
            show: "#poplist_load",
            hide: ".load-params",
            remove: "#load_event" 
        }
        // etc etc.
    };

    $("#btn_remove_event_type").click(function() {
        var fn, selector, typeConfig = $(".selected-type").attr("id");
        for (fn in typeConfig) 
            $(typeConfig[fn])[fn]();
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your input.